# Camera movement in a 2d game

Tags: javascript, html, 2d

I really wanna know how to make 2d camera movement in html and javascript, so i wrote this code which is just a character and a block so i can test if the camera movement is working. This is my code:

```js
var c = document.getElementById("screen");
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var rightPressed;
var leftPressed;
var x = (c.width - 75) / 2;
var speed = 10;

function block() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#fff";
  ctx.fillRect(390, 225, 80, 25);
}

function character() {
  ctx.fillStyle = "#00f"
  ctx.fillRect(x, 250, 50, 50);
}

function keyUpHandler(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = false;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = false;
  }
}

function keyDownHandler(event) {
  if (event.keyCode == 37) {
    leftPressed = true;
  } else if (event.keyCode == 39) {
    rightPressed = true;
  }
}

document.addEventListener("keyup", keyUpHandler, false);
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyDownHandler, false);

function draw() {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  block();
  character();

  if (rightPressed && (x + 50) < c.width) {
    x += speed;
  } else if (leftPressed && x > 0) {
    x -= speed;
  }

  requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}

requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

```css
#screen {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: #0f0;
  border: 2px solid black;
}

#headline {
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="headline">2d Camera movement</h1>
<canvas id="screen" width="500" height="300"></canvas>
```

Is there anyone who knows how to do this then please tell me, also it would be nice if you could put it into this code :)

Comment: I would recommend using [vectors](http://victorjs.org) for position, displacement, and speed (maybe also acceleration). The key input should just update the displacement. Rendering should be done in a continuous loop, independent of a keystroke.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created two classes, a `Game` and a `Ball`. The balls will move when a player presses the left or right key.

The balls know their own position and speed, the game does not care.

Just tell the ball to update according to the game's current state.

---

I adapted a good portion of code from here:

> *"[Quick Tip: How to Make a Game Loop in JavaScript](https://www.sitepoint.com/quick-tip-game-loop-in-javascript/)"*

I added ES6 classes, vector support and dynamic game element support.

---

### Demo

```js
const canvasTxt = window.canvasTxt.default;

const KeyCodeMap = {
  37: 'left',
  38: 'up',
  39: 'right',
  40: 'down',
  65: 'left',
  68: 'right',
  83: 'down',
  87: 'up'
};

Object.assign(canvasTxt, {
  align: 'left',
  vAlign: 'top',
  font: 'monospace',
  fontSize: 24
});

const main = () => {
  Game.DEBUG = true; // Enable global DEBUG mode.

  const ctx = document.getElementById('screen').getContext('2d');
  const game = new Game(ctx);

  game.gameElements.push(...[
    new Ball({
      speed: new Victor(10, 0),
      position: new Victor(game.getWidth() / 2, game.getHeight() / 2),
      color: 'red',
      size: 20
    }),
    new Ball({
      speed: new Victor(20, 0),
      position: new Victor(game.getWidth() / 2, game.getHeight() / 4),
      color: 'green',
      size: 30
    }),
    new Ball({
      speed: new Victor(20, 50),
      position: new Victor(100, 140),
      color: 'cyan',
      size: 25
    }),
  ]);

  game.redraw();
};


class Ball {
  constructor(options) {
    let opts = Object.assign({}, Ball.defaultOptions, options);
    this.position = opts.position;
    this.speed = opts.speed;
    this.size = opts.size;
    this.color = opts.color;
  }
  update(container, state) {
    if (state.pressedKeys.left && !state.pressedKeys.right) {
      this.position.subtract(this.speed);
    }
    if (state.pressedKeys.right && !state.pressedKeys.left) {
      this.position.add(this.speed);
    }
    this.checkBounds(container); // Make sure object is in-bounds...
  }
  checkBounds(container) {
    if (this.position.x > container.width) {
      this.position.x = 0;
    }
    if (this.position.x < 0) {
      this.position.x = container.width;
    }
    if (this.position.y > container.height) {
      this.position.y = 0;
    }
    if (this.position.y < 0) {
      this.position.y = container.height;
    }
  }
  draw(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(this.position.x, this.position.y, this.size / 2, 0, 2 * Math.PI, false);
    ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
    ctx.fill();
    //ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    //ctx.strokeStyle = '#000000';
    ctx.stroke();
    ctx.restore();
  }
}
Ball.defaultOptions = {
  position: new Victor(0, 0),
  speed: new Victor(0, 0),
  size: 1,
  color: '#FFFFFF'
};

class Game {
  constructor(ctx) {
    this.ctx = ctx;
    this.gameElements = [];
    this.resize();
    this.state = {
      pressedKeys: {} // Capture key pressed
    };
    this.__lastRender = 0;
    this.__animationId = null;

    window.onresize = (e) => this.resize(e);
    document.addEventListener('click', (e) => this.clickHandler(e), false);
    document.addEventListener('keyup', (e) => this.keyUpHandler(e), false);
    document.addEventListener('keydown', (e) => this.keyDownHandler(e), false);
  }

  clickHandler(e) {
    this.isRunning() ? this.pause() : this.run(); // Pause, if running
  }

  keyUpHandler(event) {
    let key = KeyCodeMap[event.keyCode];
    delete this.state.pressedKeys[key];
  }

  keyDownHandler(event) {
    let key = KeyCodeMap[event.keyCode];
    if (key) this.state.pressedKeys[key] = true;
  }

  getWidth() {
    return this.ctx.canvas.width;
  }

  getHeight() {
    return this.ctx.canvas.height;
  }

  resize(event) {
    this.ctx.canvas.width = window.innerWidth * 2
    this.ctx.canvas.height = window.innerHeight * 2
  }

  update(progress) {
    this.gameElements.forEach(gameElement => gameElement.update(this.ctx.canvas, this.state));
  }

  redraw() {
    this.ctx.clearRect(0, 0, this.getWidth(), this.getHeight());
    this.gameElements.forEach(gameElement => gameElement.draw(this.ctx));

    if (Game.DEBUG) {
      this.__renderDebugText(this.ctx);
    }
  }

  /* @private */ __renderDebugText(ctx) {
    ctx.save();
    let text = 'DEBUG OUTPUT:\n\n' + JSON.stringify(Object.assign({
      running: this.isRunning()
    }, this.state), null, 2);
    let offset = { x: 16, y: 16 };
    let bounds = { width: 280,  height: 320 };
    ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(16, 16, 16, 0.8)';
    ctx.fillRect(offset.x, offset.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    ctx.lineWidth = 1;
    ctx.strokeStyle = '#333';
    ctx.strokeRect(offset.x, offset.y, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    ctx.fillStyle = '#FFF';
    canvasTxt.drawText(ctx, text, offset.x + 4, offset.y + 4, bounds.width, bounds.height);
    ctx.restore();
  }

  loop(timestamp) {
    this.update(timestamp - this.__lastRender);
    this.redraw();
    this.__lastRender = timestamp;
    this.__animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame((ts) => this.loop(ts));
  }

  isRunning() {
    return this.__animationId != null;
  }

  run() {
    this.__animationId = window.requestAnimationFrame((ts) => this.loop(ts));
  }

  pause() {
    cancelAnimationFrame(this.__animationId);
    this.__animationId = null;
    this.redraw();
  }
}
Game.DEBUG = false; // Default is off

main();
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

canvas {
  background: #000;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/victor/1.1.0/victor.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/canvas-txt@2.0.6/build/index.js"></script>
<canvas id="screen" />
```